# Conditional Corporate RML Header with docIf

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, rml

Dears,

we have the request to print the user defined corporate header only on the first page of a business document on PDF (such as invoice, sales quotation, sales order). All other pages of the PDF reports must just contain our corporate logo.

Lucky to find the [post of Brett Lehrer](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/reportlab-conditional-table-header-15143) I tried to achieve this using

```
<header>
    <pageTemplate>
        <frame id="first" x1="1.3cm" y1="3.0cm" height="21.7cm" width="19.0cm"/>
        <stylesheet>
            <!-- style definitions in here -->
        </stylesheet>
        <pageGraphics>
            ...
            <!-- corporate logo definition in here -->
            ...
            <docIf cond="doc.page==1">
                ...
                <!-- all corporate contact data in here -->
                ...
            </docIf>
        </pageGraphics>
    </pageTemplate>
</header>
```

in the custom corporate header RML definition.

Further modified the file `./odoo/openerp/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py` in function `def _flowable(...)` to handle a `<docIf>` tag as follows

```
elif node.tag == 'hr':
    width_hr=node.get('width') or '100%'
    color_hr=node.get('color')  or 'black'
    thickness_hr=node.get('thickness') or 1
    lineCap_hr=node.get('lineCap') or 'round'
    return platypus.flowables.HRFlowable(width=width_hr,color=color.get(color_hr),thickness=float(thickness_hr),lineCap=str(lineCap_hr))
##### edit-start ####
elif node.tag == 'docIf':
    return platypus.flowables.DocIf(node.get('cond'), self.render(node))
##### edit-end ####
else:
    sys.stderr.write('Warning: flowable not yet implemented: %s !\n' % (node.tag,))
    return None
```

But this brought *not* the required result:

The corporate header prints on PDF without any of the definitions inside the `<docIf>` tags on *every* page. It seems as if the condition *never* becomes True.

Web research for days now brought no result.

Anyone of you might already solved such demand or played with conditional RML output in OpenERP/odoo?

Can you help, please? Your comments/ideas are highly appreciated.
Thanks